# CodeIgniter and PhPBB 3.1.3 integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, header, phpbb

I develop a website site based on CodeIgniter, the latest version 2.2.1 and I installed a PhPBB forum (version 3.1.3).

I would like to use the functions of the forum on my web site (like the connection/profile etc.). 
I've looked on this site : http://www.3cc.org/blog/2010/03/integrating-your-existing-site-into-phpbb3/ to simply display my pseudo.

My Controller is just a copy/paste of the first paragraph

```
class Forum_test extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
         define('IN_PHPBB', true);
         $phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : 'forum/';
         $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
         include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
         // Start session management
         $user->session_begin();
         $auth->acl($user->data);
         $user->setup();
    }
}
```

And my problem is when I try to use this code, I have the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function header() on a non-object in /var/www/forum/phpbb/session.php on line 224
```

But if I create a simple document with only

```
<?php
define('IN_PHPBB', true);

$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : 'forum/';
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);

// Start session management

$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$user->setup();
?>
```

It works (I don't have any error)

**Do you have any idea of what is wrong with my code ?**

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're problem lies here `parent::__construct();` what is the parents constructor?

Comment: This is only the constructor of the CI_Controller class which is the basic controller of CodeIgniter. Even if I remove it, it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So ... I found the solution after long research ...

https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=71&t=2287546

The solution was to add global variables to the function index

```
global $request;
global $phpbb_container;
global $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx, $user, $auth, $cache, $db, $config, $template, $table_prefix;
global $request;
global $phpbb_dispatcher;
global $symfony_request;
global $phpbb_filesystem;
```

Comment: Do you mean add `global` to the `index` method of the controller?

Comment: Yes :) But it doesn't work if you put the global variables in the constructor, so you have to C/C these lines every time you want to do something with PhpBB.

Comment: Can you please guide how to integrate phpbb forum into codeigniter site?

Answer (score 0):

I have also needed to integrate phpbb into codeigniter base website and face many problems and finally able to do it. If you need it you can find all code at  [phpbb integration in codeigniter](https://github.com/bluegaurav/phpbb-integration-in-codeigniter) it also contains phpbb version which I have used to integrate as well as doubtful. If you want to improvement in the code. Please frok me on github.

Comment: Did you use MVC structure? I saw that you used CodeIgniter, but there is no any MVC circumstantial evidence? Am I wrong?

Comment: Codeigniter is MVC based and ofcoures i have use MVC structure . i have create a library for comunicate between PHPBB and codeigniter and this libaray bulid in ci using codeiniter .

Comment: Can you give some info on github that could help to integrate it in a already built codeigniter website

Comment: As there may be lots of files needs changes for a already built in website so a small exlanation for files that needs change is good to have