# CodeIgniter 2 and MyBB Integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, mybb

I'm trying to integrate my CodeIgniter 2 site into the MyBB login system. I have found this general purpose guide.

http://community.mybb.com/thread-60422.html

I thought I might be able to put it at the top of index.php and have access to the $mybb variable on the views, but I can't access the variable inside CodeIgniter. If I print_r right after including it on the index I get all the data, but if I print_r on the view I get nothing. I figure this is a variable scope issue.

What is the best way to get access to $mybb throughout my CI models, views, and controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the codeingiter.com mybb integration on there git hub

https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter-website/blob/master/application/models/Mybb.php

They have made it so you can fork it.

Comment: also have look at this link might be use full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586272/codeigniter-and-phpbb-3-1-3-integration